# jQuery container height() not calculated properly

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors, height

`$('.container').height();` gives the wrong value when it's child elements have spacing CSS attributes on it:

```
<div class="container">
  <div style="padding: 10px;">
      weiorng3poin4gr9p34ng9p34n5g934ng5o43ng534g
      <div style="margin: 20px; ">
         eiong349ng49ng934ng59p34n5g439g5
      </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

How can I get the correct height of `.container` ?

Comment: In what way does it give a "wrong value"? Too much, too little? A jsfiddle.net example would help too.

Comment: It sound like you might want .outerHeight();

Comment: Is the margin missing an `x`?

Comment: yes, but that's only here. in my code the margin is in the css file..

Comment: hey outerHeight() instead of height() works! thanks! u should post it as answer

Comment: OK I'll edit the question as it makes a 40px difference to the reported height :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does the container `<div>` have any padding/margin/border? If so, you can try this:

```
$(".container").outerHeight(true);//will consider margin and border width as well.
```

Comment: It gives me the exact height if I add 'true'. If I leave it out then the height is much closer to the real height, but still wrong. thanks

Comment: `outHeight()` won't work properly in this instance because there is no `margin` or `padding` on the `.container div`.  That is where the calculation would happen.  See http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/